# PHP odbc truncating strings with unicode characters when reading data from FileMaker ODBC on MacOS

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, odbc

I am accessing a FileMaker database from PHP via ODBC.

Whenever a text field contains unicode characters, those characters are read properly, but the LAST character of the string goes missing.

For example: "München" becomes "Münche"

Some experiments show me that for every non-ASCII character, one more character gets truncated from the end. ("Müünchen" becomes "Müünch").

Note that WRITING INTO the FileMaker DB works just fine (and all characters appear there), as does reading and writing from a MySQL DB I've used for testing. Only when reading the data out of FileMaker via ODBC does it get mangled.

I suspected the driver, but when I use odbc_result_all() the data appears fully, with all characters intact. All other functions (odbc_fetch_into(), odbc_fetch_array(), odbc_result(), etc.) return the truncated string.

I've even looked into the source at https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/odbc/php_odbc.c but I can't quite figure out a) what does odbc_result_all() do different and b) how do I get the full string into my application?

additional details:

- PHP version: PHP 7.3.8 (cli) (built: Aug 11 2019 20:50:16) ( NTS )
- System: MacOS 10.14.6
- ODBC Driver: fmodbc.so from FileMaker, config options:

  - WideAPI                = Yes
  - UnicodeTextTypes       = Yes
  - MultiByteEncoding      = UTF-8

Comment: I've tested accessing via JDBC and Java code and the data comes out correctly there. So it more and more looks like incorrect Unicode handling somewhere in the PHP odbc library.

Comment: If you want to further narrow it down you could try using pyodbc with the same FMP ODBC driver to see if you get results similar to those you get with PHP. If you do decide to try pyodbc be sure to read the wiki notes on [Unicode](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode).

Comment: @GordThompson I actually went to PHP because I can't use python - the pyodbc driver is compiled against unixodbc, while the FileMaker odbc driver is linked against iodbc, so they don't talk to each other.

Comment: If you're still struggling with this issue it *is* possible to create a version of pyodbc that works with iODBC. You need to build pyodbc from source on a machine that has the iODBC binary components and header files installed. [I just did it on Xubuntu 20.04, but unfortunately I couldn't test it with FMP ODBC because apparently they don't offer a version of the driver for Linux. :( ]